# onBindViewHolder crashing at setText using RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to implement a custom RecyclerView.Adaper to be used on a dummy/POC RecyclerView app. I'm using [this](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview) tutorial. My model is called `Movie` and has two fields:

```
@NonNull
@PrimaryKey
private String name;

@NonNull
private Integer releaseYear;
```

So I have this class

```
MovieAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieAdapter.MyViewHolder>
```

overriding `onCreateViewHolder`, `onBindViewHolder` and `getItemCount` and defining `MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder`.

When debug line is at last line of onBindViewHolder:

```
// Involves populating data into the item through holder
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    // Get the data model based on position
    Movie movie = movies.get(position);

    // Set item views based on your views and data model
    TextView tvMovieName = viewHolder.tvMovieName;
    tvMovieName.setText(movie.getName());

    TextView tvMovieReleaseYear = viewHolder.tvMovieReleaseYear;
    tvMovieReleaseYear.setText(movie.getReleaseYear());
}
```

I get

```
Process: br.com.basicfeatures, PID: 2555
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7cf
    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:348)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5831)
    at br.com.basicfeatures.presentation.adapter.MovieAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MovieAdapter.java:45)
    at br.com.basicfeatures.presentation.adapter.MovieAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MovieAdapter.java:15)
```

This is MyViewHolder:

```
protected class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView tvMovieName;
    private TextView tvMovieReleaseYear;

    private MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.tvMovieName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_tv_movie_name);
        this.tvMovieReleaseYear = itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_tv_movie_release_year);
    }
}
```

Comment: Clean project and check id of textview correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `movie.getReleaseYear()` returns an Integer so `tvMovieReleaseYear.setText` tries to find the corresponding resource file which does not exist. So what you need is to cast `movie.getReleaseYear()` to a String

```
tvMovieReleaseYear.setText(movie.getReleaseYear() + "");
```

Comment: Turns out 7cf is 1999 in hexadecimal (integer value I'm using). Now it makes sense

Comment: Yes, hope my answer helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Convert value of `movie.getReleaseYear()` to `String`.

```
 tvMovieReleaseYear.setText(String.valueOf(movie.getReleaseYear()));
```

---

> Why it required?

Only 2 methods in `TextView` which takes integer in `setText()` and both expects `StringRes`. So when you try to set integer, it assumes you are trying to set a string from String resource.

So to set integer using `setText()` you need to convert it to string in any way.

Below are two methods which I mentioned above

```
/**
5821     * Sets the text to be displayed using a string resource identifier.
5822     *
5823     * @param resid the resource identifier of the string resource to be displayed
5824     *
5825     * @see #setText(CharSequence)
5826     *
5827     * @attr ref android.R.styleable#TextView_text
5828     */
5829    @android.view.RemotableViewMethod
5830    public final void setText(@StringRes int resid) {
5831        setText(getContext().getResources().getText(resid));
5832        mTextSetFromXmlOrResourceId = true;
5833        mTextId = resid;
5834    }
5835
5836    /**
5837     * Sets the text to be displayed using a string resource identifier and the
5838     * {@link android.widget.TextView.BufferType}.
5839     * <p/>
5840     * When required, TextView will use {@link android.text.Spannable.Factory} to create final or
5841     * intermediate {@link Spannable Spannables}. Likewise it will use
5842     * {@link android.text.Editable.Factory} to create final or intermediate
5843     * {@link Editable Editables}.
5844     *
5845     * @param resid the resource identifier of the string resource to be displayed
5846     * @param type a {@link android.widget.TextView.BufferType} which defines whether the text is
5847     *              stored as a static text, styleable/spannable text, or editable text
5848     *
5849     * @see #setText(int)
5850     * @see #setText(CharSequence)
5851     * @see android.widget.TextView.BufferType
5852     * @see #setSpannableFactory(Spannable.Factory)
5853     * @see #setEditableFactory(Editable.Factory)
5854     *
5855     * @attr ref android.R.styleable#TextView_text
5856     * @attr ref android.R.styleable#TextView_bufferType
5857     */
5858    public final void setText(@StringRes int resid, BufferType type) {
5859        setText(getContext().getResources().getText(resid), type);
5860        mTextSetFromXmlOrResourceId = true;
5861        mTextId = resid;
5862    }
```